# Most elegant way of delayed or repeatable initializing

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I am trying to rewrite extremely ugly class in one application at work. In one of our classes, there are hundreds of lines of code that ensure initialization and re-initialization of some classes. Currently, this is done in the awful brute force-y way, where you write your init code and manually copy it to re-init part (as they are very similar).

Because of this , I started to rewrite it to a form of a list of delegates which are then called with a parameter in both places (bool isReinit). Then I noticed that most of the delegates are also identical, as the initialization process of 90 percent of the classes is identical. This means that I should be able to create some default initialization function to simplify the code drastically. Currently I created something like this :

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVS5UT

I also created class CustomInitializer which implements IInitializer and only takes one Func as a parameter and runs it in Initialize, for the cases where the initialization is a lot different.

Now, this simplified and anonymized piece of working code, but it works. The problem is that the whole approach is very awkward and the constructor signature is ugly as hell. Is there some way to simplify this ? I can't find any pattern or approach that would help me ? Any step towards better code is welcome and maybe I am just missing something.

There is also another catch. One solution I figured out would be to store the property pairs (var1a + var1b, var2a+var2b, ..) in an object and pass it directly to Initialize method. But this would mean moving the properties, which is sadly not possible at the moment, because the file has over 18k lines and code reviewers would kill me for changing third of them because of refactoring of one method (even if its a long one). I need to leave the target properties (var1a, var1b, var2a, ..) where they are now. This could also mean that there is no elegant way to solve this.

I am using .NET 4.0, C# 5.0

EDIT: I have no access to the initialized types (another stupid catch)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not simply replace the old instance with a new one? Re-initializing could be done by simply referencing a new instance instead. Anyway, a class so big doesn`t make any sense. What's the cohesion between all these properties? What is the single reponsability of this class? What behaviors does it have? What it means to re-initialize this class? Sometime it's better to explain the initial problem and leaving all the current solution pieces out of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

> the file has over 18k lines

Wow, looks like a lot of fun.

It is absolutely good to try to improve it. And believe me, whatever your co-workers may think, there is nothing else to do than refactoring here, unless this code does not need to evolve.

But, it seems to me you go on the path of complexity, trying to be DRY instead of trying to be expressive. The idea of having StandardInitializer and CustomInitializer managing lambdas is extremely complex. The initialization of a class should be in the class it is responsible to initialize. If some behaviors are really shared, they may share a base class or a collaboration class.

I recommend you this discussion on [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122014/what-are-the-key-points-of-working-effectively-with-legacy-code). As you'll see and probably already know, the first key point is to have tests.
Please don't try to refactor such a class without a test harness. Otherwise you'll introduce regression, you'll be frustrated, and your co-workers will be comforted in their vision that nothing can be done here without breaking everything.

And don't forget if tests are hard to create, it's because of bad code, not because tests are expensive. Bad code is expensive.

After some tests protect you, try to think in terms of responsibility and life cycle. For example in a WPF application, it is a common issue to have "initializable" ViewModel because they do some async web service call to initialize themselves.

In this case, the object with the responsibilty of lifecycle for a given ViewModel, has also the responsibility to init it. If it manages several Initializable view models, then this kind of code is fine:

```
foreach (var initializable in initializables)
{
    initializable.Initialize();
}
```

But please, whatever solution you choose, keep a clear separation between Initialize and Reinitialize (if they have things in common, make them call an internal shared function). It is a very bad idea to write stuff like:

```
init.Initialize(true);
```

It clearly states that the behavior of your Initialize function will change depending of a boolean value. If you have 2 behaviors, you should have 2 functions with clear naming.

Comment: I didn't mention (I thought it's not important), that the initialized objects are being constructed by a COM library so I have no access to the class and can't add the init to the class itself. I would need to create some mirrored helper class and keep it in there or as an extension method. Also there are no tests and sadly there will not be test . . so I intentionally try to keep the changes as small as possible (because regression).